# How do i get my image to move with arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, image

im trying to get my image luvmush to move with arrow keys. but im unable to figure out how to properly link and and stuff. thanks! Im just trying to make a game in js.

```
var gsc = document.getElementById("gsc");
var context = gsc.getContext("2d");
//gsc= game screen
this is the  image that im trying to make move.
var luvmush = document.getElementById("luvmush")
var luvmush = new Image();
luvmush.src = "./images/Pinky.png"
context.drawImage(luvmush, 100, 400, 30, 30);

//array for key states
let keys = new Array (0xff).fill(0);

//listeners
document.addEventListener('keydown', e=> keys[e.keyCode] = 1);
document.addEventListener('keyup', e=> keys[e.keyCode] = 0);

//key codes
const LEFT = 37;
const UP = 38;
const RIGHT = 39;
const DOWN = 40;

let dx = keys[RIGHT] - keys[LEFT];
let dy = keys[DOWN] - keys[UP];

//moving
x += dx * t * SPEED;
y += dy * t * SPEED;

What should i change? or add?
```

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Canvas_How_to/Image/Move_image_with_keyboard_arrow_key.htm

Comment: I hope this helps

Comment: Question edited and [tag:java] programming tag removed. No sense drawing the wrong experts to this question.

Comment: Thanks so much didi. im going to try it out right now and let you know.

Comment: Okay so my code now works and im able to move the image however, my backround screen and everything disapears as soon as i move it. why is that? https://jsfiddle.net/shakir12993/wenat8v0/ thats my code